# JQuery methods and DOM properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am confused as to when I can use the DOM properties and when I could use the Jquery methods on a Jquery object. Say, I use a selector

```
var $elemSel = $('#myDiv').find('[id *= \'select\']')
```

At this point, $elemSel is a jquery object which I understand to be a wrapper around the array of DOM elements. I could get a reference to the DOM elements by iterating through the $elemSel object/array (Correct?)

My questions:
1. Is there a way to convert this $elemSel into a non JQuery regular array of DOM elements?
2. Can I combine DOM properties and JQuery methods at the same time (something like this)

```
$elemSel.children('td').nodeName
```

(nodeName is DOM related, children is JQuery related)

EDIT: What's wrong with this?

```
$elemSel.get(0).is(':checked')
```

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks for the responses. I understand now that I can use the get(0) to get a DOM element. Additional questions:

1. How would I convert a DOM element to a JQuery object?
2. If I assign "this" to a variable, is that new var DOM or JQuery? If it's JQuery, how can I convert this to a DOM element? (Since I can't use get(0))

   var $elemTd = $(this);
3. When I do a assignment like the one above, I have seen some code samples not include the $ sign for the variable name. Why?
4. And as for my original question, can I combine the DOM properties and JQuery functions at the same time on a JQuery object?

   $elemSel.children('td').nodeName

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll need to .get(0) the result to get the DOM-ready object.

```
var myBox = $("div#myBox");
alert(myBox.get(0).id); // "myBox"
```

Read "[Peeling Away the jQuery Wrapper and Finding an Array](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/12/peeling-away-the-jquery-wrapper)" by Cody Lindley

---

**Re: Edit:** `.is()` is not a native javascript method. When you run `.get(0)`, you are no longer working off of the jQuery object, therefore you cannot expect to run jQuery methods from it.

If you want to run `.is()` on a specific result, use the [`:eq(index) selector`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index), or the [`.eq(index) method`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq#index):

```
$("div:eq(1)").is(":checked"); // gets second div
$("div").eq(1).is(":checked"); // gets second div
```

---

**Re: Edit # 2**

> Bob, you really should create new
>   questions, rather than asking more and
>   more here.

Converting a dom element to jquery object is done by passing it in a selector:

```
var myBox = document.createElement("div");
var myBoxJQ = $(myBox);
```

Assinging `This` to a variable. Depends on when you do it. If by "this" you're referring to a jQuery object, then `this` will be a jQuery object. You can convert it by following `this` with `.get(0)`.

When `this` is referring to a jQuery object, you don't need to wrap it in the $(). This is redundant.

And lastly, `$elemSel.children('td').nodeName` can be done like this: `$elemSel.children('td')[0].nodeName` or
`$elemSel.children('td').get(0).nodeName`, where the 0 is the index of which item to access.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, if I want to work with the individual elements of the Jquery object and want to run Jquery methods on them, do I have to use "each"? Is there any other way?

Comment: The jQuery object IS an array. So you can treat every instance of a jQuery object like an array. Access the first item in that array to run your native javascript methods on it.

Comment: may I request you to have a look at a jquery question on a different topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137404/jquery-find-div-class-name-at-a-certain-position-while-scrolling ?

Answer (score 2):

There is also a shortcut for get(index) function:

```
$(selector)[0].nodeName
```

Soruce: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/get#index

Answer (score 1):

Because there can be more than one match in jQuery selectors you need to get the elements out of the "array".

You can use the [get](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/get) method to return a single DOM element or an array or DOM elements.

eg:

```
var elims = $("div").get();
for(var i in elims)
    alert(elims[i].nodeName);
```

**Edit:**

`$elemSel.get(0).is(':checked')` will not work because you are getting the Dom object and then trying to use jQuery functions on it.  If you want to get a single jQuery element use [eq](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq#position).

```
$elemSel.eq(0).is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to call native DOM method you can use get(index). Or if you want to use jQuery Object method, you should wrap a native DOM element with jQuery, which will convert the DOM element into a jQuery Object, so all the methods will be available. 
http://www.linxinshan.com/?p=339