# Inline SVG and jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, svg

I have an inline SVG in an HTML file. This SVG has an animation inside with an id "move".

If I call this animation using jQuery 1.9.1 to modify its attributes, like so:

```
$("#move").attr("from", "500");
```

it works perfectly (in Firefox 16.0.1 at least, I haven't tested other browsers).

If I try to launch the animation using jQuery like this:

```
$("#move").beginElement();
```

it doesn't work, again in Firefox.

If I call it using JavaScript like this:

```
var move=document.getElementById("move");
move.beginElement();
```

it works.

How do I call the `beginElement()` function using jQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery methods and DOM properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557533/jquery-methods-and-dom-properties)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you're asking...

```
$("#move")[0].beginElement();
```

Without knowing more I can't say much more than that.  `jQuery()[0]` returns the DOM element, rather than the jQuery object.